Error reading file from S3: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 502) with GetObjectRequest
I am trying to read file from localstack s3 and getting below error

"message":"Error reading file from S3: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 502, Request ID: null)","exception":"","level_value":40000
Even i tried with single class locally it's working fine
enter code here  public static void main(String[] args) {
AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("test", "test");
StaticCredentialsProvider staticCredentialsProvider =
    StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);

S3Client s3Client =
    S3Client.builder()
        .region(Region.of("us-east-1"))
        .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4566"))
        .credentialsProvider(staticCredentialsProvider)
        .forcePathStyle(true)
        .build();
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
    GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket("test").key("file.txt").build();
ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> response = s3Client.getObjectAsBytes(getObjectRequest);
System.out.println(response);

}
Can anyone help here why am i getting 502 in docker.
I tried with local java file it seems to be working.
Getting 502 with docker

Can you share your docker setup as well? Are you trying to run this setup when localstack starts? Any logs you can provide from the localstack output would also be helpful!

Issue was related to s3 url defined in properties file
older
aws.endpoint-s3=${AWS_ENDPOINT_S3:http://localhost:4566}
new change
cloud.aws.s3.endpoint=${AWS_ENDPOINT_S3:http://localhost:4566}
key name should be defined like this only
